# LoggingEvent.ExceptionObject is null

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I am currently attempting to write a custom appender for log4net.  My Append method:

```
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
    ... stuff
}
```

I'd like to capture `loggingEvent.ExceptionObject` within the method.  I can trigger the Append method with

```
throw new Exception("Test");
```

but the `ExceptionObject` is always null.  Every other function of this program works; I can call `RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent)` and get the correct string back.  I just can't get the exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Hoping this helps someone!  : )

When catching the exception, I was using the `Fatal(ex)` method.  This was converting the exception object to a string message.  Changing the call to `Fatal(ex, ex)` or `Fatal("Fatal: ", ex)` correctly passed the exception to the custom appender.